# Kafka Consumer at Java - no records received

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

My question is about Kafka consumer at Java

1. Started the kafka server

   ```
   bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
   ```
2. Created Topic

   ```
   bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test
   ```
3. Created Producer

   ```
   bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test
   ```
4. Created Consumer

   ```
   bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic test
   ```

All above things I did in the terminal, working fine and able to receive the logs properly at the consumer. Running the below Consumer ( in Java ), But not receiving any records.  It is keep on pooling at

```
ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = kafkaConsumer.poll(1);
```

and no records received

Given below my java Consumer code

```
package com.myCompany.kafka.subscription;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;

public class KafkaSubscription {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "192.168.95.217:9092");
        props.put("zookeeper.connect", "192.168.95.217:2181");
        props.put("group.id", "test-consumer-group");
        props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
        props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
        props.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
        props.put("session.timeout.ms", "30000");
        props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");

        KafkaConsumer<String, String> kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
        System.out.println("properties loaded");
        kafkaConsumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("test"));
        kafkaConsumer.seekToBeginning(Collections.emptyList());
        while (true) {
            ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = kafkaConsumer.poll(1);
            for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
                System.out.printf("offset = %d, value = %s", record.offset(), record.value());
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Please tell me out to receive the messages at java Consumer class, Am I doing anything wrong in the configuration ?
What for the "group.id" in the properties ?

Given below the logs at java consumer end.

---

```
0    [main] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig  - ConsumerConfig values: 
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 1000
    auto.offset.reset = earliest
    bootstrap.servers = [192.168.95.217:9092]
    check.crcs = true
    client.id = 
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    enable.auto.commit = true
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    group.id = test-consumer-group
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    interceptor.classes = null
    internal.leave.group.on.close = true
    isolation.level = read_uncommitted
    key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
    max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
    max.poll.records = 500
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 305000
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    session.timeout.ms = 30000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer

4    [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer  - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=test-consumer-group] Initializing the Kafka consumer
118  [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata  - Updated cluster metadata version 1 to Cluster(id = null, nodes = [192.168.95.217:9092 (id: -1 rack: null)], partitions = [])
138  [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name fetch-throttle-time
157  [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name connections-closed:
163  [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name connections-created:
164  [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name successful-authentication:
164  [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name failed-authentication:
165  [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name bytes-sent-received:
166  [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name bytes-sent:
168  [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name bytes-received:
169  [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name select-time:
171  [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name io-time:
198  [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name heartbeat-latency
198  [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name join-latency
199  [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name sync-latency
202  [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name commit-latency
209  [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name bytes-fetched
210  [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name records-fetched
210  [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name fetch-latency
211  [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name records-lag
220  [main] INFO  org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser  - Kafka version : 1.0.0
220  [main] INFO  org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser  - Kafka commitId : aaa7af6d4a11b29d
223  [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer  - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=test-consumer-group] Kafka consumer initialized
properties loaded
224  [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer  - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=test-consumer-group] Subscribed to topic(s): test
224  [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator  - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=test-consumer-group] Sending GroupCoordinator request to broker 192.168.95.217:9092 (id: -1 rack: null)
386  [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient  - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=test-consumer-group] Initiating connection to node 192.168.95.217:9092 (id: -1 rack: null)
488  [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name node--1.bytes-sent
489  [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name node--1.bytes-received
490  [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name node--1.latency
491  [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector  - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=test-consumer-group] Created socket with SO_RCVBUF = 65536, SO_SNDBUF = 131072, SO_TIMEOUT = 0 to node -1
492  [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient  - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=test-consumer-group] Completed connection to node -1. Fetching API versions.
492  [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient  - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=test-consumer-group] Initiating API versions fetch from node -1.
506  [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient  - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=test-consumer-group] Recorded API versions for node -1: (Produce(0): 0 to 5 [usable: 5], Fetch(1): 0 to 6 [usable: 6], ListOffsets(2): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], Metadata(3): 0 to 5 [usable: 5], LeaderAndIsr(4): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], StopReplica(5): 0 [usable: 0], UpdateMetadata(6): 0 to 4 [usable: 4], ControlledShutdown(7): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], OffsetCommit(8): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], OffsetFetch(9): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], FindCoordinator(10): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], JoinGroup(11): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], Heartbeat(12): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], LeaveGroup(13): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], SyncGroup(14): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], DescribeGroups(15): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], ListGroups(16): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], SaslHandshake(17): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], ApiVersions(18): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], CreateTopics(19): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], DeleteTopics(20): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], DeleteRecords(21): 0 [usable: 0], InitProducerId(22): 0 [usable: 0], OffsetForLeaderEpoch(23): 0 [usable: 0], AddPartitionsToTxn(24): 0 [usable: 0], AddOffsetsToTxn(25): 0 [usable: 0], EndTxn(26): 0 [usable: 0], WriteTxnMarkers(27): 0 [usable: 0], TxnOffsetCommit(28): 0 [usable: 0], DescribeAcls(29): 0 [usable: 0], CreateAcls(30): 0 [usable: 0], DeleteAcls(31): 0 [usable: 0], DescribeConfigs(32): 0 [usable: 0], AlterConfigs(33): 0 [usable: 0], AlterReplicaLogDirs(34): 0 [usable: 0], DescribeLogDirs(35): 0 [usable: 0], SaslAuthenticate(36): 0 [usable: 0], CreatePartitions(37): 0 [usable: 0])
506  [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient  - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=test-consumer-group] Sending metadata request (type=MetadataRequest, topics=test) to node 192.168.95.217:9092 (id: -1 rack: null)
514  [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata  - Updated cluster metadata version 2 to Cluster(id = jm5HyHZbT1mlgdZxinD8oA, nodes = [localhost:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)], partitions = [Partition(topic = test, partition = 0, leader = 0, replicas = [0], isr = [0], offlineReplicas = [])])
516  [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator  - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=test-consumer-group] Received GroupCoordinator response ClientResponse(receivedTimeMs=1515749439145, latencyMs=134, disconnected=false, requestHeader=RequestHeader(apiKey=FIND_COORDINATOR, apiVersion=1, clientId=consumer-1, correlationId=0), responseBody=FindCoordinatorResponse(throttleTimeMs=0, errorMessage='null', error=NONE, node=localhost:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)))
516  [main] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator  - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=test-consumer-group] Discovered coordinator localhost:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
516  [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient  - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=test-consumer-group] Initiating connection to node localhost:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
520  [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | test-consumer-group] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator  - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=test-consumer-group] Heartbeat thread started
520  [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=test-consumer-group] Sending synchronous auto-commit of offsets {}
520  [main] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=test-consumer-group] Revoking previously assigned partitions []
520  [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator  - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=test-consumer-group] Disabling heartbeat thread
520  [main] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator  - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=test-consumer-group] (Re-)joining group
523  [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator  - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=test-consumer-group] Sending JoinGroup ((type: JoinGroupRequest, groupId=test-consumer-group, sessionTimeout=30000, rebalanceTimeout=300000, memberId=, protocolType=consumer, groupProtocols=org.apache.kafka.common.requests.JoinGroupRequest$ProtocolMetadata@19d481b)) to coordinator localhost:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
525  [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name node-2147483647.bytes-sent
526  [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name node-2147483647.bytes-received
527  [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name node-2147483647.latency
528  [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector  - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=test-consumer-group] Connection with localhost/127.0.0.1 disconnected
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.PlaintextTransportLayer.finishConnect(PlaintextTransportLayer.java:50)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.finishConnect(KafkaChannel.java:106)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:444)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:398)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:460)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:238)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:214)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:174)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.joinGroupIfNeeded(AbstractCoordinator.java:364)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureActiveGroup(AbstractCoordinator.java:316)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:295)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:1138)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1103)
    at com.myCompany.kafka.subscription.KafkaSubscription.main(KafkaSubscription.java:30)
533  [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient  - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=test-consumer-group] Node 2147483647 disconnected.
534  [main] WARN  org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient  - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=test-consumer-group] Connection to node 2147483647 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
534  [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient  - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=test-consumer-group] Cancelled JOIN_GROUP request RequestHeader(apiKey=JOIN_GROUP, apiVersion=2, clientId=consumer-1, correlationId=3) with correlation id 3 due to node 2147483647 being disconnected
534  [main] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator  - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=test-consumer-group] Marking the coordinator localhost:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) dead
635  [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator  - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=test-consumer-group] Sending GroupCoordinator request to broker localhost:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)
635  [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient  - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=test-consumer-group] Initiating connection to node localhost:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)
635  [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name node-0.bytes-sent
636  [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name node-0.bytes-received
637  [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  - Added sensor with name node-0.latency
638  [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector  - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=test-consumer-group] Connection with localhost/127.0.0.1
```

---

Comment: Your consumer code worked in my 1.0.0 local test environment.  What's the version of Kafka you use? Would it be failed to consume records even after a new `group.id` was specified?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply, I am using " kafka_2.11-0.9.0.1  ". Not getting any records when the  java application ( consumer ) runs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application is working fine on my Kafka 1.0.0 based installation, what version are you using ? A couple of other things to mention :

The console consumer application is running using the Old Consumer which is deprecated so instead of using `--zookeeper localhost:2181` you can use `--bootstrap-server localhost:9092`.

Then in your application the `zookeeper.connect` properties isn't a consumer property and you don't need it. You need just the `bootstrap.servers` property for connecting to a kafka broker.

Finally, as you asked, the `group.id` is the consumer group name to which the consumer will belong.

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, I am using  " kafka_2.11-0.9.0.1 " version installation

Comment: No, I will try with that and revert

Comment: Just tried with 1.0.0, not receiving anything at java application, Able to receive the at terminal consumer app.

Comment: Now I am running both producer ( terminal ), consumer ( terminal ), consumer ( java application ) all at the kafka server only. ( To state there should not be any network issue )

Comment: can you try to switch using "localhost" instead of the IP (192.168.95.217) in the Java application please ? Another try : what happens running only the Java application and the console producer but not the console consumer (even if they belong to different consumer group so they should receive messages both even if topic has just 1 partition).

Comment: Hi, Tried with both , i.e., "localhost" in java app, and only java app as consumer. No other consumer subscribed with the kafka instance. Not Getting anything at java application ( kafka consumer )

Comment: well I have just copied/pasted your Java application and run it along with broker and the console producer and consumer ... it's really working fine with following output : offset = 0, value = Hello
offset = 1, value = Apache
offset = 2, value = Kafka  .... can you add log4j to your Java application and a related log4j.properties with INFO as log level in order to check what happens in the native Kafka client.

Comment: Added the log message received at java app in the Question

Comment: It seems to me that the broker is not reachable or is not replying because my trace go ahead finding the coordinator and so on. Can you provide the Kafka broker log as well ?

Comment: Able to get logs if run at same system with " localhost ",  Getting connection refused if I try to connect via remote system. Updated Logs, thanks for your support

Comment: any hint on why I am getting " connection refused " if I run the same application remotely.

Comment: Maybe the remote machine is behind a firewall which blocks any incoming connection requests on port 9092. Remember that the kafka cluster (kafka + zookeeper) need to be accessible from outside if your client application is runnig remotely (port 2181 and 9092 needs to be open).

Comment: gopal.m@ptpll354 /data/myCompany/TASKS/8. 2017-2018_PS2/KAFKA $ telnet 192.168.95.217 2181
Trying 192.168.95.217...
Connected to 192.168.95.217.
Escape character is '^]'.
^CConnection closed by foreign host.
gopal.m@ptpll354 /data/Kafka/TASKS/8. 2017-2018_PS2/KAFKA $ telnet 192.168.95.217 9092
Trying 192.168.95.217...
Connected to 192.168.95.217.
Escape character is '^]'.
^CConnection closed by foreign host.

Comment: Checked with telnet from my local to remote on both the ports 2181 and 9092, able to connect successfully.

Comment: do you have any chance to get the Kafka broker log from the remote machine ?

Comment: but it seems that you are trying to connect to localhost than the remote machine ...

Answer (score 1):

Because you are running kafka on remote server you need to uncomment `advertised.listeners` inside of servers.properties.

For example: `advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.95.217:9092`

After that restart your kafka server and your remote consumer.

For more checkout this blog post https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/.

> tl;dr : You need to set advertised.listeners (or KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS if you’re using Docker images) to the external address (host/IP) so that clients can correctly connect to it. Otherwise they’ll try to connect to the internal host address–and if that’s not reachable then problems ensue.

It gives a pretty concise explanation better than the actually documentation.

I'm running Kafka version `2.13`